# can't get ContinueWhenAll to execute in UI thread

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

The following is operating with a C# winforms application in .net 4.0

I have a list of tasks that execute in parallel. Once their execution is complete, there's a block of code I want to execute (relates to post-process validation). If any of the tasks fail, I want the exception to flow up the call stack to the UI level (I have a global exception handler that needs to be invoked).

I understand that ContinueWhenAll is not a blocking method. I also know that ContinueWhenAll is kicking off a new task.  But I can't seem to make this task run in the same thread as the UI.
The exception is visible when running as Debug. But without debugging, the Continue'd task fails in its own thread and the exception goes unhandled and is lost.

I think my use of **TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously** is the cause (MSDN *"the continuation will be run on the same thread that causes the antecedent task to transition into its final state"*).  Is there anyway I can force execution on the UI thread? Or am I using the wrong tool for the job?

```
//Being called in the UI thread
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in workList)
{
   tasks.Add(item.DoWorkAsync);
}
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), LoadComplete, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, context); 

...

private void LoadComplete(Task[] tasks)
{
    var errors = (from t in tasks where t.Exception != null select t.Exception);
    if (errors.Count() > 0)
            throw new AggregateException(errors.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: @Servy, 4.0.  I know there are all kinds of goodness in 4.5 for TAP.

Comment: @MoSlo: You can install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` to get `async` support on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some digging and the way in which I'm using ContinueWhenAll is correct for the scenario I have (the tasks are IO related).

.net 4.5 has all kinds of good tools such as *async / await* but we need to keep this project in 4.0 for now.  So the simplest way to ensure that LoadComplete runs in the UI thread is BeingInvoke

```
private void LoadComplete(Task[] tasks)
{
    //Invoke on UI thread
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {

                    var errors = (from t in tasks where t.Exception != null select t.Exception);
                    if (errors.Count() > 0)
                        throw new AggregateException(errors.ToArray());

                });
    }
```

Comment: As an addendum. My golden rule is that UI thread synchronization should always be implemented by the consuming UI code. This stops foundation code being polluted with unnecessary threading garbage.

Answer (score 1):

I just knocked together a very quick app to see what happens in .net 4 and 4.5 and after 10 tests all the continuation code ran on the UI thread

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        tasks.Add(new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Task 1:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)));
        tasks.Add(new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Task 1:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)));

        var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), LoadComplete, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, context);

        tasks.ForEach(task => task.Start());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private void LoadComplete(Task[] tasks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completion Task" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between your example and mine, where my task is created and started (item.DoWorkAsync) and yours are started after being added to the continuation task.
That said, I tried adjusting my code to start the tasks after being added to the continuation task, but keep getting an error that I can't start a continuation task. I think this is because ExecuteSynchronously is creating a task hierarchy.

Comment: So DoWorkAsync creates and starts the task? IS there anything special happening in the DoWorkAsync method?

Comment: Also what context are you starting the tasks on?